# Why am I getting a 404 error for OPTIONS for only my custom Devise API calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cors

I've been struggling trying to get my API working with CORS. I followed the instructions from: 
http://kellishaver.tumblr.com/post/40758797489/cors-headers-with-devise

Added this to my application.rb:

```
config.middleware.use "Cors"
config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, "Cors"
```

Added this to /lib/cors.rb:

```
class Cors
  def initialize(app)
  @app = app
end

def call(env)
   status, headers, response = @app.call(env)

   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT'
   headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728001"

   [status, headers, response]
 end
end
```

As I'm trying to solve the same problem and allow my API to be called from Chrome (or anywhere else). Problem is that all my calls work except for my custom API Devise calls. My Devise API calls get a weird 404 error for "OPTIONS" when I look at it in Chrome dev tools.

My Devise API looks like this...

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                 :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

   respond_to :json
   def create
   warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")

   render :status => 200,
       :json => { :success => true,
                  :info => "Logged in",
                  :data => { :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token },
                  :id => current_user.id}
  end
...
```

Any ideas on why my custom Devise API calls aren't working but my others are?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Just switched to the rack-cors gem instead of the code above and followed the blog example here: 
https://gist.github.com/AdrianTeh/3561310